# How to make voice requests using Houndify in Python?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, houndify

I am using python 3.6. I am planning to incorporate houndify in a project that I'm working on. I want to use the Houndify API to make voice requests (using only a few domains like Weather, Map, Knowledge, Wikipedia, etc.). The documentation on the page left me kind of confused, so I would really appreciate it if anyone could explain (with example code of course) how I can use the Houndify API to get results. 
PS: I Don't want to use my browser in any way. All I want to use is my python code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the documentation in the README?  It has a lot of useful info.  If there is a more specific question, please let me know.

https://docs.houndify.com/sdks/docs/python

Comment: i just wanted a basic api call python program, which would take a voice input and give the result in JSON format....I am very new to python, and an example code would have really helped me out

Comment: If you download the SDK, you should be able to run a command like:  ./sample_text.py <CLIENT ID> <CLIENT KEY> '<QUERY>' for text or ./sample_wave.py <CLIENT ID> <CLIENT KEY> test_audio/whattimeisitindenver.wav for audio.  These, and other sample commands are on the link above.  You can find you CLIENT ID and CLIENT KEY on your developer dashboard.  These are used to authenticate your request.  I hope that helps.